# Проектирование БД

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, архитектура

Я делаю систему которая включает **ленту объявлений**. Пользователь подписывается на несколько категорий. Затем ему выдается лента новостей со всех категорий на которые он подписан: 
Я описал для этого такую архитектуру:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но понимаю что получить "Ленту" я сначала должен получить список всех категорий на которые подписан пользователь, а только потом запрашивать данные из таблицы Посты.

Вообще насколько это правильное решение? Может как-то можно построить архитектуру, чтобы получать ленту **одним запросом**?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: SQL вообще очень мощная штука. Он позволяет практически любые данные из любого количества таблиц в любом разрезе получить одним запросом, особенно если структура БД _нормализована_ (как у вас).  Если вам покажется, что какую то информацию получить одним запросом нельзя - значит надо глубже изучить SQL :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Одним запросом

```
SELECT p.* FROM Posts p
INNER JOIN Subscriptions s ON s.category_id = p.category_id
-- также join images img on img.post_id = p.id но тут группировать придётся
WHERE s.user_id = :user_id
```

Нормальная у вас архитектура, каждая сущность - своя таблица.
Ничего лишнего, все связи на месте.